How to list all servers in YugabyteDB cluster?
I was looking to get all ip's of my hosts for all masters and tservers, do we have any specific command through which I can list all of the host ip's?

If using YSQL, the yb_servers() function can be helpful:
yugabyte=# SELECT host, cloud, region, zone FROM yb_servers() ORDER BY zone;
    host    | cloud |  region   |   zone
-------------+-------+-----------+------------
 10.37.1.65  | aws   | us-east-1 | us-east-1a
 10.37.1.204 | aws   | us-east-1 | us-east-1b
 10.37.1.249 | aws   | us-east-1 | us-east-1c
(3 rows)

But this won’t include the yb-masters.
For the list of yb-master servers you can use yb-admin list_all_masters.
